# Upper bound of number of integral ideals in the ring of integers of an algebraic number field.

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be an algebraic number field of degree $n.$ Let $O_{K}$ denote the ring of integers of $K.$ Let $a$ be a non zero rational integer. Then show that $a$ can belong to atmost $a^n$ integral ideals of $O_{K}$.

I've tried using conjugates of elements of integral basis to differentiate amongst ideals containing $a$ but have not had much success. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In a number field, if $\mathfrak {a, b}$ are ideals, then $\mathfrak b\subset \mathfrak a$ if and only if $\mathfrak a\mid\mathfrak b$. Try this with $\mathfrak b = (a)$.

Comment: Yeah so if I start with a prime factorisation of $(a)$ = $P_{1}^{e_1}...P_{r}^{e_r}$ and if $J$ is any ideal containing $a$ then $J | (a)$ so there should be at most $(e_1 + 1)...(e_r + 1)$ choices for $J$ right? But how is this equal to $a^n$ ?

Comment: It's quite a crude bound. If $a$ is a rational prime, then $(a)$ has at most $n$ prime ideal factors (some may have multiplicities), so has at most $2^n$ factors. If $a$ is composite, it can't have that many prime factors.

Answer (score 2):

The bound in the comments is definitely better, but for completeness this is a stab at what the person originally posing the question might have intended.

Two ingredients: a quotient of a Dedekind domain by a nonzero ideal is PID, and the size of $\mathcal O_K/(a)$ is the norm of $a$.

Any ideal containing $(a)$ corresponds to an ideal of the quotient $\mathcal O_K/(a)$, which by above is a principal ideal that we can write as $(\bar b)$ for $\bar b$ in the quotient. There are at most $|\mathcal O_K/(a)|$ choices for $\bar b$ (in reality, most of these collide) and by the second fact above that means there are at most $N(a) = a^n$ possibilities.